# React Native - Navigate to screen - Invalid hook call

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View,Text} from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';

import Epics from './screens/tmp';
import Pager from './screens/Pager';

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
 Home: {screen: Epics},
 Page: {screen: Pager}
},{initialRouteName: 'Home'});

const Stack = createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Stack />;
  }
}
```

Trying to navigate to a screen through a custom component:

```
import { ActivityIndicator, Image, StyleSheet, View, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from 'react-navigation-hooks';

import AuthorRow from './AuthorRow';

export default class Card extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    fullname: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    image: Image.propTypes.source.isRequired,
    linkText: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    onPressLinkText: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    epicId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  };

  state = {
    loading: true,
  };

  getNav(){
    return useNavigation();
  }

  handleLoad = () => {
    this.setState({ loading: false });
  };

  render() {
    const { fullname, image, linkText, onPressLinkText, epicId, prop } = this.props;
    const { loading } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <View>
        <AuthorRow
          fullname={fullname}
          linkText={linkText}
          onPressLinkText={onPressLinkText}
        />
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.getNav().navigate('Pager')} underlayColor="white">
          <View style={styles.image}>
            {loading && (
              <ActivityIndicator style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill} size={'large'} />
            )}
            <Image
              style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
              source={image}
              onLoad={this.handleLoad}
            />
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    aspectRatio: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.02)',
  },
});
```

From above code, trying to navigate using:

**import { useNavigation } from 'react-navigation-hooks';**

**getNav(){ return useNavigation(); }**

**this.getNav().navigate('Pager')**

It errors our stating: **Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.**

How do I navigate using "useNavigation()" or how do I get "this.props.navigation" reference in a component? (I am new to React Native, please help me understand)

## Update

I tried using "this.props.navigation" and it gives me undefined error:
[image]

Comment: You can't use hooks in class based components, turn it into functional component.

You can pass navigation as props to custom component from parent component.

Comment: How do I pass navigation as props?

Comment: could you update your new code??
[check this may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48203708/how-do-i-pass-navigation-props-from-parent-component-to-header)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    //In Card component remove this
    //import { useNavigation } from 'react-navigation-hooks';

    //Add this line
    import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation';

    class Card extends React.Component {

      static propTypes = {
        fullname: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        image: Image.propTypes.source.isRequired,
        linkText: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        onPressLinkText: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        epicId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      };

      state = {
        loading: true,
      };

    //Remove this
    //  getNav(){
     //   return useNavigation();
      //}

      handleLoad = () => {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      };

      render() {
        const { fullname, image, linkText, onPressLinkText, epicId, prop } = this.props;
        const { loading } = this.state;

        return (
          <View>
            <AuthorRow
              fullname={fullname}
              linkText={linkText}
              onPressLinkText={onPressLinkText}
            />
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() =>  
//Make change like this
 this.props.navigation.navigate('Pager')} underlayColor="white">
              <View style={styles.image}>
                {loading && (
                  <ActivityIndicator style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill} size={'large'} />
                )}
                <Image
                  style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
                  source={image}
                  onLoad={this.handleLoad}
                />
              </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      image: {
        aspectRatio: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.02)',
      },
    });
//Make change like this
    export default withNavigation(Card)
```

Comment: Good Solution. Worked for me

Answer (score 3):

@sayog you are breaking the rule of hook brother.
Could you try this?

`const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
 const navigation = useNavigation();`

make sure you put it **after** your state declaration

**Note**: Dont' use class component for Hook. use Functional Component for hook

Comment: In my case I had to put it after useEffect too

Answer (score 1):

here is your mistake

**mistake**

onPress={() => this.getNav().navigate('Pager')

replace with

onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Pager')

here is the example

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating/

https://medium.com/@marizu_makozi/navigating-between-screens-or-activities-using-react-navigation-library-68d57657d81

Another example code

```
class FirstScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'First',
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    navigate('Second');
    fetch('http://apiserver').then( (response) => {
      navigate('Second');
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <AppLogo />
    );
  }
}

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  First: {
    screen: FirstScreen,
  },
  Second: {
    screen: SecondScreen,
  },
});
```

Comment: Since I want on click, i tried

```getNav(){
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    navigate('Pager');
  }
```

It gives me TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.navigation.navigate)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use hooks inside Class component convert your class component to a functional component or use navigation object for navigations by passing navigation props to your component `this.props.navigation.navigate('screenName')`

Comment: ```getNav(){
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    navigate('Pager');
  }
```

Even if i try above, it gives me TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.navigation.navigate)

Comment: I have the same problem and nothing found on internet how to access navigation in a class component.